# Perl, Change the Case of Letter at { character

Tags: regex, perl

I am a perl newb, and just need to get something done quick and dirty. 
I have lines of text (from .bib files) such as

```
Title = {{the Particle Swarm - Explosion, Stability, and Convergence in a Multidimensional Complex Space}},
```

How can I write a regex such that the first letter after the second { becomes capitalised.

Thanks

Comment: Well, `s/{{\K(\w)/uc($1)/e` for example (the `/e` makes it evaluate the replacement side as code) ... but are you _certain_ that you may just unleash that on your whole files?  Will it catch all cases you need?  Will it not clip something else you didn't mean to?

Comment: that seems to get rid of the braces, i need the braces preserved (dw i have a copy of my original file!)
Title = The Particle Swarm - Explosion, Stability, and Convergence in a Multidimensional Complex Space}},

Comment: Yeah, that was the original where I forgot the `\K` ... comment edited, look again please ... there's an "answer" posted now as well.

Comment: perfect thank you so much!!!

Comment: Added a snippet that allows for (optional) spaces, probably what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, for the question as asked

```
$string =~ s/{{\K(\w)/uc($1)/ge;
```

whereby `/e` makes it evaluate the replacement side as code.  The `\K` makes it drop all previous matches so `{{` aren't "consumed" (and thus need not be retyped in the replacement side).

If you wish to allow for possible spaces:  `$string =~ s/{{\s*\K(\w)/uc($1)/ge;`, and as far as I know bibtex why not allow for spaces between curlies as well, so `{\s*{`.

If simple capitalization is all you need then `\U$1` in the replacement side sufficies and there is no need for `/e` modifier with it, per comment by [Grinnz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5848200/grinnz). The `\U` is a generic [quote-like operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators), which can thus also be used in regex; see under *Escape sequences* [in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions), and [in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#More-on-characters%2c-strings%2c-and-character-classes).

I recommend a good read through the tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).  That will go a long way.

However, I must also ask: Are you *certain* that you may indeed just unleash that on your whole file? Will it catch all cases you need? Will it not clip something else you didn't mean to?

Comment: `s/{{\K(\w)/\U$1/g` doesn't require the `/e` modifier, as `\U` works in double-quoted strings.